# Topics against objects in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, topics

I can see that topics are available in Chatter posts in Lightning Experience, but I can't see which topics are assigned to a given object when looking at its record.

For example, I might have assigned several topics to a given Account in classic by entering them in the banner across the top of the chatter section.  I can then see those topics whenever I view the Account - they're visible in the same place as I entered them.

However, I can't see them anywhere in Lightning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to these release notes for Summer '17: [Use Topics to Organize Your Content in Chatter](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_chatter_topics_in_lightning.htm)

> You can use topics on a record’s feed, but topics on objects aren’t available in Lightning Experience.

This feature is expected to arrive in Summer '18: [Organize Records with Topics](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_general_topics_on_records.htm)